# Not able to find Magento 2.0.4 default theme files

Tags: theme, magento-2.0.4

I have recently installed Magento 2.0.4 on to my local machine, I am trying to find files so that I can customize the product page layout according to my requirement. Everybody are pointing me to `app/design/frontend/Magento` and telling me that I can find the theme files over there, but when I go to that folder it's just empty. Please guide me where to find the theme files so I can customize the pages.

Answer (score -1):

For me, the theme file are in `siteroot/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank`

Depending on how you installed Magento, the theme files can be in different locations. In my case I installed by downloading the zip from magento.com and went through the installer process. If you used Composer to install it, your results might be different. But so far the only two places I have seen them are in the `/vender` or the `/app` folders.

In the case of adding override files to your theme for any of the different product page elements, you would navigate to `<siteroot>/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view` and find the template that you want to edit. Grab that template and copy it over to `<siteroot>/app/design/frontend/vender_namespace/theme_name/Magneto_Catalog/templates/product/view`

If you don't have this folder structure, just create it and move the files over that you need. If you enable template hints in the admin (stores-> config-> developer-> template hints) you should see that template with your theme's path in the hints, letting you know you copied it over correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have found out the theme folder in the vendor folder. Can you please help me in pointing out to the files that can edited to customize the product page layout.

Comment: I updated my answer to help you out with finding and adding the templates to your theme